# Get Process threads relationships in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have tried the below mentioned code to currently running process thread details.

```
Process proc=Process.GetCurrentProcess();

var threads=proc.Threads;

foreach (ProcessThread pt in threads)
{

//  Code

}
```

From the above code i can able to get the list of threads and the corresponding thread state, etc.

Now my requirement is to get the relationship between these threads ( which one is the parent thread and which is the child thread and the relationship between them). Please help me and send me some sample codes to achieve this requirement.

Thank You.

Comment: Processes can have parent/child relationships, but I'm not sure threads do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever maybe he is referring to a thread spawning additional threads?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I gotta agree on that one. I'm pretty sure threads, in .NET at least, are simply contained in the `AppDomain`.

Comment: @JBelter - that may be so - but such information isn't tracked (unlike process parent/child which is tracked by Windows)

Comment: So, Threads don't have parent\child relationship. Am i correct?

Comment: There is no way, to determine which thread spawned another.